# How to iterate over string variables of a class object in C++?

Tags: c++

So here I have a class definition of a Car and then I create a carObject with it. I want the user to input values for all the variables in the carObject. As you see here, I have managed to get user input, but my approach to this problem is inefficient in my opinion.

I notice that all of the user inputs, except for the first one are very similar. I would like to use a loop of some kind to iterate over the declaration statements, or blocks of statements, and change the variable every time. I would like to put an if statement to enter different input only for the first iteration of the loop. I know that in bash I could use a string variable to stand for the variable name, but I don't know if that's possible in C++.

Notice that the object name does not change, but only the variables that are associated with it. I also use the same word for the user input, which preferably should be changed every iteration. I also have a series of arrays which are named similarly. The purpose of these arrays is to tell the user what options are available for a particular variable.

Although I have previous programming experience, I am relatively new to C++. A block of code that would serve as a solution to my problem that involves a call to another function would suit my purposes. Here is my code below.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    class Car {
    public:

    string Name;
    string Model;
    string Color;
    string Transmission;
    string Category;
    };

    int main() {

    Car CarObject;

    string modelOptions [3] = { "Ferrari", "Porsche", "Nissan" };
    string colorOptions [4] = { "Blue", "Red", "Green", "White" };
    string transmisionOptions [2] = { "Automatic", "Manual" };
    string categoryOptions [3] = { "A", "B", "C" };

    cout << "Enter " << "name" << " for Car 1." << endl;
    cin >> carObject.Name;
    cout << endl;

cout << "Enter " << "model" << " for Car 1." << endl;
cout << "Options are:";
for (const string &text: modelOptions) {
    cout << " " << text;
}
cout << "." << endl;
cin >> carObject.Model;
cout << endl;

cout << "Enter " << "color" << " for Car 1." << endl;
cout << "Options are:";
for (const string &text: colorOptions) {
    cout << " " << text;
}
cout << "." << endl;
cin >> carObject.Color;
cout << endl;

cout << "Enter " << "transmission" << " for Car 1." << endl;
cout << "Options are:";
for (const string &text: transmissionOptions) {
    cout << " " << text;
}
cout << "." << endl;
cin >> carObject.Transmission;
cout << endl;

cout << "Enter " << "category" << " for Car 1." << endl;
cout << "Options are:";
for (const string &text: categoryOptions) {
    cout << " " << text;
}
cout << "." << endl;
cin >> carObject.Category;
cout << endl;

...

return 0;

}
```

Comment: May I ask you how you can predict user input are very similar?

Comment: Define a function that corresponds to the general "user input of a field" block of code. Its parameters include an options vector. Its result is a string.

Comment: What do you mean by "predict user input"? The for loop in each "input block" iterates over the respective "options" array and displays all of the options that the user is allowed to input.

Comment: @Galaxy You said `I notice that all of the user inputs, except for the first one are very similar.` in the 2nd paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Car::InputParameter(string& param, const string &msg, const vector<string>& options)
{
    cout << msg << endl;

    for (const string &text: options) {
          cout << " " << text;
    }

    cout << "." << endl;

    cin >> param;

    cout << endl;
}
```

I think you might want something like this. You just call it for each member.

Answer (score 0):

This block of code:

```
cout << "Enter " << "category" << " for Car 1." << endl;
cout << "Options are:";
for (const string &text: categoryOptions) {
    cout << " " << text;
}
cout << "." << endl;
cin >> carObject.Category;
cout << endl;
```

… can be replaced with a call to a function like this:

```
carObject.Category = userInput( "category", categoryOptions );
```

Clearly it returns a `string` (that is, a `std::string`).

The options argument should better be made a `vector<string>`.

---

Then just replace the other similar blocks with ditto calls to that function.

---

Is it a good idea to make that function a member function of `Car`?

No.

Consider, for example, how to then use `Car` in a GUI program (Graphical User Interface).

Comment: 100K! You made it!